# Doesn't… (negative), but…. (short positive)

Tags: negation, ellipsis, transitivity

I've just learned a very basic way of shortening sentences:

> **He likes tea** (positive), **but she doesn't** (short negative).
>
> **I haven't got a car** (negative), **but my sister has** (short positive).

But, what about:

> **She doesn't like coffee** (negative), **but I do** (short positive).

According to google results this seems not very usual. Only got [6 results for the search phrase "doesn't like coffee, but I do"](https://www.google.com.tr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22doesn%27t+like+coffee%2C+but+I+do%22).

I am wondering, is the sentence above correct? or shall I have to say:

> **She doesn't like coffee**, **but I like.** (?)

Comment: Note that `"likes coffee, but I don't"` has only 13 results. So, it may be because of *coffee*. :-)

Comment: Yes, well seen:)

Comment: A wildcard search yields better (or, at least more) results.  I get hundreds of millions of hits for the quoted search string `"* doesn't like * but I do"`, and nearly as many for `"* doesn't like it but I do"`.

Answer (score 4):

The Google search engine wasn't designed to teach you English. And English is a language with a lot of flexibility. It's likely that someone's made the same statement as you, but phrased differently. If you've learned proper grammar rules (which it seems that you have, because your initial constructions are correct), don't question them when a robot tells you nobody says that.

> She doesn't like coffee, but I like.

This isn't correct. Only the auxillary verb can be used in the shortened part of the sentence, as you've already done in your other examples. The verbs "have" and "do" are both intransitive, so they can be used in this way. Like is not an intransitive verb.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Google wasn't designed to teach English but it can help. If a well-structured sentence, involving coffee which is one of the most used products in the world has only 6 results, I have some reasons to wonder. But I understand your point and I will pay attention to not base my questions on Google results. Thank you!

Comment: @viery365 I see your point. have you tried "father hates grandfather"? it's perfect in grammar but has 3 results.. see? ;)

Comment: Yes, that's is amazing:) I've checked, and yes, 3 results:)

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother too much about the Google search results.

There is nothing wrong with your example and you can use it perfectly anywhere.

If you still think you need to change it, add *it* at the end of the sentence.

> She doesn't like coffee, but I like it.

Comment: You are most welcome.